# функция сама вызывается - при навешивании слушателя внутри другой функции

Tags: javascript

Пример здесь на [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/stivman/pen/LYRmvjP?editors=0011)

Добавляю слушатель внутри функции `document.addEventListener('click', closePopup)`, а он сразу исполняется с текущим event. :(

Помогите понять, почему? и как это исправить?

```
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');

function closePopup(event) {
  console.log(event.target)
  if (!event.target.closest('.popup')) {
    removeClassActivePopup()
  }
}

function removeClassActivePopup() {
  button.classList.remove('button_active')
  popup.classList.remove('popup_visible')
  document.removeEventListener('click', closePopup)
}

function addClassActivePopup() {
  // если закомитить навешивание слушателя - работает
  // функция closePoupup вызывается при навешивании с текущим event и     закрывает popup
  document.addEventListener('click', closePopup)
  button.classList.add('button_active')
  popup.classList.add('popup_visible')
}

function showPopupSetting(e) {
  if (button.matches('.button_active')) {
    removeClassActivePopup()
  } else {
    addClassActivePopup()
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', showPopupSetting)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы добавляете обработчик события документу до того, как это событие "всплывет" до документа.

```js
function clickDocument() {
  console.log('clickDocument');
}
function clickButton() {
  console.log('clickButton');
  document.addEventListener("click", clickDocument);
}

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", clickButton);
```

```html
<button id="test">Click</button>
```

---

```js
function clickDocument() {
  console.log('clickDocument');
}
function clickButton(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('clickButton');
  document.addEventListener("click", clickDocument);
}

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", clickButton);
```

```html
<button id="test">Click</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Благодаря вам, я подрос в понимании JavaScript :)

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле проблема в 3 параметре [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

> **useCapture**
>
> Если равно true, useCapture указывает, что пользователь желает начать
> захват. После инициализации захвата все события указанного типа будут
> отправлены в зарегистрированный listener перед отправкой в какой-либо
> EventTarget под ним в дереве DOM. События, восходящие вверх по дереву,
> не будут вызывать слушателей, которым назначено использовать захват.
> Смотрите DOM Level 3 Events для более детального объяснения. Значение
> useCapture по умолчанию равно false.

```js
function clickDocument() {
  console.log('clickDocument');
}
function clickButton() {
  document.addEventListener("click", clickDocument, true);
  console.log('clickButton');  
}

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", clickButton);
```

```html
<button id="test">Click</button>
```

против

```js
function clickDocument() {
  console.log('clickDocument');
}
function clickButton() {
  document.addEventListener("click", clickDocument);
  console.log('clickButton');  
}

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", clickButton);
```

```html
<button id="test">Click</button>
```

Обратите внимание на первый клик, до того как навешан был обработчик.